# Power BI :: Show a Table of Measures on Rows Instead of Columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

**GOAL:** I'm trying to create a table in Power BI with different measure.

Every measure has a different filter, for example:

```
Realised Savings Azure App Service v2 = 
CALCULATE(SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]), FILTER ( 'Usage details', 'Usage details'[meterCategory] = "Azure App Service" && CONTAINSSTRING('Usage details'[meterName.1], "v2") ))
```

```
Realised Savings Azure App Service v3 = 
CALCULATE(SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]), FILTER ( 'Usage details', 'Usage details'[meterCategory] = "Azure App Service" && CONTAINSSTRING('Usage details'[meterName.1], "v3") ))
```

```
Realised Savings DTU = 
CALCULATE(SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]), FILTER ( 'Usage details', 'Usage details'[meterCategory] = "SQL Database" && CONTAINSSTRING('Usage details'[meterName.1], "DTU") ))
```

```
Realised Savings vCore = 
CALCULATE(SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]), FILTER ( 'Usage details', 'Usage details'[meterCategory] = "SQL Database" && 'Usage details'[meterName.1] = "vCore" ) )
```

```
Realised Savings VMs = 
CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency] ), FILTER ( 'Usage details', 'Usage details'[meterCategory] = "Virtual Machines"  ) )
```

**PROBLEM:** I have checked the totals and they are alright. I'm happy, I reached my goal!

But when I try to put them into a table, horror: they create columns instead of rows:

[image]

I don't want to have them like that.

What I want is this:

| MeterCategory | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Realised Savings Azure App Service v2 | 4147.091 |
| Realised Savings Azure App Service v3 | 4889.731 |
| Realised Savings DTU | 12915.273 |
| Realised Savings vCore | 238.528 |
| Realised Savings VMs | 5859.370 |

So how to pivot this table?

I tried the Matrix but it seems like it's not working.

Should I create a table instead of 5 different measures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a matrix and switch values to rows.

[image]

Comment: You saved my day again, David. <3

Comment: Strangely both subtotals are enabled  but the Raw subtotal is not showing: https://snipboard.io/0QgKir.jpg Do you know why?

Comment: You'll need to approach it differently if you want to total all your measures because totals don't work that way in PowerBI. If you want a super simple approach, just add another measure which sums your other 5 measures and call it "Total".

Comment: Just curious, how would you approach it differently? Would you create a table? With one DAX per row?

Comment: I can think of quite a few ways and it all depends on your requirements and how you intend to use the data. You could do this as a calculation group for instance or as a single measure and switch statement or using a disconnected table. It depends what your model looks like and the end requirements so no single answer I'm afraid.

Comment: In fact, why don't you make 'Usage details'[meterCategory] a dimension and have just a single measure doing all the work. It will give you totals for each category and also grand totals too.